# Is there a term to describe someone who is rarely at home?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm referring to someone who travels a lot, completely consumed with his job.

Answer (score 1):

They are known as a [***road warrior***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/road%20warrior)

Defined by Merriam Webster as:

> a person who travels frequently especially on business

Answer (score 1):

**Company Man**

> "Company man" also is a term relating to a "yes-man", or someone who will do anything demanded of them by those who are supervising them: that is, **someone whose primary allegiance is to the company rather than colleagues or friends**.

I think it's a good fit as it's 'technical' definition refers to someone "on-site"; a representative of a company based elsewhere.

> The company man is the on-site representative of the operating/exploration [oil] company and is in overall charge of the drilling and associated activities [of the 'the rig crew', who are usually a contracted third party].

–[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Company_man), emphasis and [additions] are mine.

Apologies for using more than one, but if someone can come up with a single word that has *no other meaning whatsoever*, I'll be impressed. Also, e.g., *workaholic* has no inherent connotation of travel.

Answer (score 1):

***Knight of the road***  is another definition for someone whose job requires a lot of travelling:

> - a commercial traveller
> - a lorry driver

The Free Dictionary