# Contractors becoming part of company they are working for

Tags: expressions

What's the term when a contractor (or other person) who is technically employed by company A but works so much/closely with company B, that they feel more loyal to company B or assimilate better with company B? May or may not lead to the person actually switching employers to company B.

Going native? Going rogue?

Comment: Translating to my experience, Company A is in the business of supplying people to a Government Agency (GA), and is quite aware that some (not all) of its (Company A's) employees want to work for the GA.  Working for Company A is a stepping-stone for these employees, and everybody involved understands this.

Comment: I'd say it was a prime example of Stockholm Syndrome, having had lengthy experience of the deadening effect on the psyche of working in the public or quango sector. But perhaps that's just me being cynical.

Comment: This other question isn't [related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267749/is-there-a-term-to-describe-someone-who-is-rarely-at-home/267760) but I think my answer is: an *on-site, company man*.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that the employee works for Company A "in name only."

Answer (score 0):

You could say the employee was [co-opted](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=co-opt) by Company B

> To neutralize or win over (an independent minority, for example) through assimilation into an established group or culture: *co-opt rebels by giving them positions of authority.*

*American Heritage Dictionary*

A more neutral term for the placement of an employee with another company or group is the verb [second](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/second)

> Transfer (a military officer or other official or worker) temporarily to other employment or another position:
>   *I was seconded to a public relations unit*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 0):

When I worked as a consultant, we referred to it as [*expatriating*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expatriate):

> to leave one's native country to live elsewhere;
>
> also :  to renounce allegiance to one's native country

There is some wiggle room between what you're asking and the denotation. The fact that it was (at least in my circles) fairly commonly used, makes me think that there isn't a more apropriate word.

Answer (score 0):

It's wishful thinking until you start actually moonlighting and then the last step is making it your day job. The only expression I can think of is: *That's how the world works.*